# VB.Net How to add a String to Settings

Tags: vb.net, save, my.settings

Currently I am working with My.Settings / Settings.settings and everything works great so far.
I know how to overwrite / save Settings, how to Load them but I would like to know how to add new Settings with a Button and a Textbox.

Let's say the Program has one textbox and a button next to it. Now if you type 'saveme' into it and press that button it will add the text to My.Settings like so:

For Name it will be 'saveme' for Type it will be 'String' and for Scope it is 'User' and as Value it should be nothing.

Is it possible to add something like that even when the program is already running?
Found some stuff but you have to restart the program for that and I want to change these Settings while running.

Comment: A Setting can be a `Specialized.StringCollection`. You can add items to it, or remove them.

Comment: Otherwise, see [SettingsProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsproperty) class. You can also manage class objects and serialize these objects as JSON or XML.